# Including libraries like Box2D, GLUT

Tags: c++

I have this very basic problems everytime I start working on project.
Let's say for example I want to use GLFW library.

I know how to compile library, because its usually explained on github, docs page... But the problem happens when I want to use library

- I need to include header files (.h). How do I know what is the path to include those required files?
- Then I need to compile files with flags like: "-lGL -lXrandr -lGLU..." How do I know what are these flags? I usually can't find it easily

Basically is there any "recipe" on how to START using libraries? I mean documentations are usually really good, but I can't even get to use them as fast as I would want. Setting everything up takes me too much time.

Comment: most of the time you have to provide your compiler with include directories and linker with library itself. you can check documentations of gcc and ld, to begin with.

Answer (score 1):

You can set your build system in many ways.

You could for example use [cmake](http://www.cmake.org/), which has it's own way of picking libraries.

If you opt for make, then you could use [pkg-config](http://linux.die.net/man/1/pkg-config) to get compiler and linker options for a particular library (which you have to install). Then you get compiler options for opengl like this:

```
pkg-config --cflags gl
```

and linker options :

```
pkg-config --libs gl
```