# How to configure a OpenGl development environment in Ubuntu with Code::Blocks and GLFW, GLEW, GLM, SOIL2?

Tags: c++, ubuntu, opengl, graphics, codeblocks

I want to configure a development environment of OpenGL in Ubuntu using Code::Blocks.

I'm not having success, I want to make a developing environment where I use GLFW, GLEW, GLM, SOIL2.

I've downloaded some libraries, but I can't link the files to my Code::Blocks project because I don't know where the libraries is located in my operating system installation. I've read some things about CMake but I can't recognize very what this software is, I would like to know if is really is necessary to compile theses libraries before the installation.

If possible someone could help me with this task?

Comment: If you haven't got a clue about setting up libraries, start from [Glitter](https://github.com/Polytonic/Glitter), it is a predefined project that includes "the usual suspects" for opengl graphics.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Including libraries like Box2D, GLUT](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21604336/including-libraries-like-box2d-glut) (Requires knowing how to set project build options in your IDE, Code::Blocks. That is, speak up if that question is not sufficient.)